# Creating desktop.ini with PowerShell for custom folder icon not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to create desktop.ini files within folders, that reference a .jpg in a subfolder in order to give the parent folder a custom image. This works doing the process manually (right click folder > properties > customize > choose FILE).

Assume a folder structure like so:

```
C:\Test
---> Folder1
   ---> Fullsize
   ---> image.jpg
---> Folder2
   ---> Fullsize
   ---> image.jpg
```

Before the manual process, the parent folder ('Folder1') has attributes of: `'Directory'`.

After the manual process, the folder has attributes of `'ReadOnly, Directory'`. The 'Fullsize' subfolder retains the original attribute of `'Directory'`.

The desktop.ini file is created with content like so:

```
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic
Logo=C:\Test\Folder1\Fullsize\image.jpg
```

Additionally, encoding is UTF-8, and the file properties are set to HSA (`'Hidden, System, Archive'`).

**Immediately after clicking ok, the folder shows a preview of the image.**

Turning this into the code equivalent for another folder, we have:

```
$folder2 = 'C:\Test\Folder2'
$folder2Image = "$folder2\Fullsize\image.jpg"

$ini = @"
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic
Logo=$Folder2Image
"@  

Set-ItemProperty $Folder2 -Name Attributes -Value 'ReadOnly'

# Out-File creates UTF-8 with BOM so use [System.IO.File]
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$Folder2\desktop.ini", $ini)
$inifile = Get-Item "$Folder2\desktop.ini"
$inifile.Attributes = 'Archive, System, Hidden'
```

**Despite this, folder2 will not show an image preview.**

[image: Folder view]

Checking the attributes of Folder1 and Folder2 (Get-Item $path | Select Attributes), and the desktop.ini files them show them to be identical.

The encoding and actual content of desktop.ini is identical except for the path to the image. The path to the image is correct. Files contain CRLF at the end of each line. I have even ensured the path to the image is in the correct case (not that it should matter).

Thoroughly stumped. What else could the manual process be doing that I'm missing?

[image: desktop.ini files in Notepad++]

Windows 10: Version 1607 (OS Build 14986.1001)

Comment: Note: If you copy and paste this code into a PowerShell shell, it'll create a desktop.ini with LF and not CRLF.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop.ini must be updated using a Shell API method in order for the Shell/Explorer to be notified:

```
function Set-FolderImage($folder, $imagePath) {
    # make a temporary folder with desktop.ini
    $tmpDir = (Join-Path $env:TEMP ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()))
    mkdir $tmpDir -force >$null
    $tmp = "$tmpDir\desktop.ini"
    @"
[ViewState]
FolderType=Generic
Logo=$imagePath
"@ >$tmp
    (Get-Item -LiteralPath $tmp).Attributes = 'Archive, System, Hidden'

    # use a Shell method to move that file into the destination
    $shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
    $shell.NameSpace($folder).MoveHere($tmp, 0x0004 + 0x0010 + 0x0400)

    # FOF_SILENT         0x0004 don't display progress UI
    # FOF_NOCONFIRMATION 0x0010 don't display confirmation UI, assume "yes" 
    # FOF_NOERRORUI      0x0400 don't put up error UI

    del -LiteralPath $tmpDir -force
}
```

Usage:

```
Set-FolderImage 'R:\Temp' 'R:\33983.jpg'
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried splicing your extra steps into my existing function and then resorting to running your function itself, but it doesn't work for me. I even used the folder structure you used (that's to say, an empty folder and specifying an image sitting outside of it (rather than my structure)). Tried it on a different W10 machine (1607 14393.693) and still no luck! I'm curious if this works under W7 but don't have a machine to test on at the moment.

Comment: This code works in windows 10 and 7. Let me see your adapted version please.

Comment: Make sure you've switched to icon view mode in Explorer, IIRC it doesn't display custom images in the small/detailed view.

Comment: I was using your own code in the end (eliminating possible change causing the error). I've always had icon view turned on. Easiest way to show this is a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/muPi0)

Comment: I can reproduce the problem after updating Win10. No ideas at the moment, maybe later.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, what version and build are you on now?

Comment: Win 10.0.14393.

Comment: So far I can tell is that the method in this answer definitely works for custom folder icons (not images).

Comment: I'm trying to do the same here and I get the same result! I guess I might have to add to my script a way to create small .ico files and do this with the folder's icon instead. It's kind of a bummer that this is so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The real trick is to perform this operation **on the folder**:

```
(Get-Item $Folder -Force).Attributes = 'ReadOnly, Directory'
```

Antoher cool tip when working with hidden files:
In any explorer window, to toggle hidden files by pressing these keys consecutively:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>